# Using \MakeUpperCase with math symbols throws an "Improper alphabetic constant" error after June 2022 Latex update

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I have a few custom command to ensure all vectors, matrices, etc styles are consistent throughout my document. Here is one:

```
\newcommand*{\mat}[1]{{\MakeUppercase{\symbfup{#1}}}}
```

This used to work fine, but I started getting lots of "Improper alphabetic constant" errors after updating Latex and traced it down to the case where I try to make math symbols uppercase.

Here's a MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand*{\mat}[1]{{\MakeUppercase{\symbfup{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\def\sample{0123ABCDabcd\Delta\Gamma\Omega\alpha\beta\gamma}
% all work fine
\[ \sample \]
\[ \symbf{\sample} \]
\[ \mathbfup{\sample} \]
\[ \mathbfit{\sample} \]

% fails
\[ \mat{\beta} \]
\[ \mat{\sample} \]

\end{document}
```

Is there a known workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you maybe expect that `\MakeUppercase{\beta}` produces something else than `\beta`?

Comment: When we are using Unicode math (for example in OpTeX), then `$\uppercase{α}$` works.

Comment: @wipet It would work here too: the issue is that `\beta` expands to `\mitbeta` with `unicode-math`, and that's an implicit char

Comment: I wonder (based on @wipet's comment) what output you are expecting here. A 'raw' `α` for example (the Greek text letter, U+03B1) will be changed, but e.g. U+1D6FC (`MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL ALPHA`) will not as it doesn't have a case mapping. `unicode-math` uses the math symbols, so you won't get a change.

Comment: @egreg not really, \beta could still be \beta (and not \Beta). That was the behaviour previously. Although I could see both solutions as valid.

Comment: @LucasBarcelos I'm not sure about what “consistency” means. In my opinion, if you want to get “B” in output (for a math symbol), you type in “B”, not “b”

Comment: @egreg, it is a fair point, perhaps the better description would be to be able to consistently _change_ the notation on a document. If you want to change the vector notation from, say, boldface lowercase to uppercase italics, you could do so by just changing the command definition.

Comment: @LucasBarcelos With the risk of getting two different objects with the same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to adjust the code to allow for implicit chars in text changing. For the present, try

```latex
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand*{\mat}[1]{{\MakeUppercase{\symbfup{#1}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset_eq:NN \__text_change_case_cs_check_aux:nnN \__text_change_case_cs_check:nnN
\cs_gset:Npn \__text_change_case_cs_check:nnN #1#2#3
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \__text_change_case_cs_check_aux:nnn
      { \__text_token_to_explicit:N #3 } {#1} {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__text_change_case_cs_check_aux:nnn #1#2#3
  { \__text_change_case_cs_check_aux:nnN {#2} {#3} #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\def\sample{0123ABCDabcd\Delta\Gamma\Omega\alpha\beta\gamma}
% all work fine
\[ \sample \]
\[ \symbf{\sample} \]
\[ \mathbfup{\sample} \]
\[ \mathbfit{\sample} \]

% fails
\[ \mat{\beta} \]
\[ \mat{\sample} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would caution though that `\MakeUppercase` expects 'text', which would have math mode _inside_ it (to be skipped): the input here is a bit odd

Comment: While avoiding the error is probably sensible, I also think that the input doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JosephWright, is there a more sensible alternative for this use case? That is, a situation in which I could simply edit the `\mat` command to change the style of matrix variables throughout the document?

Comment: Perhaps just inverting the sequence of commands, i.e. `\newcommand*{\mat}[1]{\symbfup{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}` would suffice if one doesn't expect the symbol case to change?

Comment: @JosephWright I just tested your proposed solution and unfortunately the error persists.

Comment: @LucasBarcelos My change is set up to work against release `expl3`: you'll have a slightly different codepath in the TL'22 one (and it depends on exactly how you set stuff up). If you can let me know what you get as a date in the line `L3 programming layer <...>` in your `.log`, I might be able to make a suggestion that will work with the release you have.

Comment: @JosephWright, thanks so much. This is what I get: `L3 programming layer <2023-02-22> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`

Comment: @LucasBarcelos Updated fix should now work